# Distinguish between conjugacy class 4A and 4B (ATLAS).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, computer-algebra-systems, gap

Is any one aware of how to distinguish between the conjugacy classes 4A and 4B in the group M$_{12}$ in GAP. Both centralizers have an order of 32 and I can't seem to find there being any difference between them?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the code to reproduce what you're seeing? Otherwise you are shutting a lot of people out who could otherwise help you by making the question inaccessible.

Comment: What do you mean by _difference_? In a small example $G = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, for example, are there some difference between conjugacy classes 3a and 3b?

Comment: @Orat

For example, the centralizer orders of 2A and 2B are different in the group M$_{12}$. Is there any difference between 4A and 4B (since they have the same centralizer order). If not, are they just identical conjugacy classes of order 4?

Answer (score 4):

In GAP,

```
gap> c:=CharacterTable("M12");
gap> AutomorphismsOfTable(c);
Group([ (14,15), (6,7)(11,12) ])
gap> ClassNames(c){[6,7,11,12,14,15]};
[ "4a", "4b", "8a", "8b", "11a", "11b" ]
```

returns a group of those class permutations (6/7 are classes 4A/B) that can be undone by a character permutation. (In a small case as this you could even do so by hand). Thus as far as *ordinary* representation theory is concerned there is no way how you can distinguish classes 4A and 4B (with the caveat that identifying one also makes a decision for classes 8A/B) and you can decide arbitrarily.

The reason for this is that the classes fuse together under an outer automorphism of $M_{12}$.

(In theory (but not here) there could be classes that are indistinguishable under ordinary representations, but become distinguished under modular representations; unless you really start looking at modular representations this level of subtlety will be of no concern.)